# How soon after updating expire_logs_days param and restarting sql will old binlogs get deleted?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5, mysql-5.1, binlog

MySQL 5.1.x | InnoDB | Windows

My mysql data directory is starting to fill up with bin logs.

I currently have the following settings configured in my windows mysql server:

```
[mysqld]
log-bin
server-id=1
binlog-do-db=foodb1
binlog-do-db=foodb2
expire_logs_days=25
```

I'm planning to change the expire_logs_days setting to `expire_logs_days=10` and bounce the mysql service.  How soon after making this change can I expect the old bin logs to get clear out.

Is this only done as part of a nightly scheduled task? Or should this be immediate?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It will be handled immediately on mysql startup.

You do not have to wait for a mysql restart.

First, set `expire_logs_days` to be 10 in /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-bin
server-id=1
binlog-do-db=foodb1
binlog-do-db=foodb2
expire_logs_days=10
```

Next, log in to mysql and run this

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE (date(now()) + interval 0 second - interval 10 day);
```

Note the query's date and time

```
mysql> select date(now()) + interval 0 second - interval 10 day;
+---------------------------------------------------+
| date(now()) + interval 0 second - interval 10 day |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2012-12-11 00:00:00                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Thus, the [PURGE BINARY LOGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/purge-binary-logs.html) command will delete all binlogs whose datetime stamp predates `2012-12-11 00:00:00`.

Finally, run this command

```
SET GLOBAL expire_logs_days = 10;
```

That's it. No restart needed for installing [expire_logs_days](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days).

As for the replication parameters, yes restart is required.

Comment: Brilliant response.  Thank you.  I appreciate the detail.

Comment: Please refresh, I corrected a typo.

Comment: Just to note that expire_logs_days is now deprecated in MySQL 8.0 (per the detail in the link given by @RolandoMySQLDBA). Use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead going forward.